# turning on jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hosting, host

I have website A: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3264697/calc/v2/index.html
It is working as intended, 100%.

I have website B: http://pe2kasb.net63.net/
It is not working as intended. Website B is a file for file mirror of A.

I assume then, this is something wrong with the host. Looking at the Javascript console, the error appears to be related to the host:

[screenshot here http://img825.imageshack.us/img825/4782/unlednwe.png](http://img825.imageshack.us/img825/4782/unlednwe.png)

Need I contact them, or is there something I can do...? I'm new to JQuery, and I believe that's what is the root of the issue but... i'm not sure.

Comment: The script paths your specify are invalid.

Comment: Voting to close as not a real question, not constructive, too localized, not helpful for community.

Comment: To solve such problems in the future, try using Firebug in Firefox.  This will clearly show that a file is missing.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the silly question. I was using Chrome's "firebug", I'll try Firebug next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are loading JQuery from `../v2/media/js/jquery.js` which does not seem to exist...

To solve the issue and improve the speed of the website

1. do not store JQuery on the server, rather load it from a 3rd party (Google works well)
2. use JQuery minified version

To load JQuery from Google you can just use:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("jquery", "1");
</script>
```

More information [here](http://code.google.com/apis/loader/)

EDIT: note that the above automatically loads the minified version of JQuery. If, for whatever reason (?) you wanted to load the uncompressed version you could use

```
google.load("jquery", "1", {uncompressed:true});
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to load jQuery from `../v2/media/js/jquery.js` but there is no such file in the second website.

I recommend that instead of hosting JQuery yourself, you use a hosted version:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

[This post](http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/) explains the reasons.

Answer (score 1):

You have invalid jQuery path at http://pe2kasb.net63.net/

Replace

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../v2/media/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

with

```
<script type="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Also you have dataTable.js missing.

Answer (score 0):

Look what http://pe2kasb.net63.net/v2/media/js/jquery.js refers to.
The file does not exist.
Upload it or include it from another location.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that jQuery is correctly linked, currently jQuery is supposed to be at "../v2/media/js/jquery.js" on "http://pe2kasb.net63.net/", which means go back one folder then enter "/v2/media/js/jquery.js".